# Reversing a String using a LinkedList based Stack

Tags: java, string, linked-list, stack, reverse

The assignment given to me is this: Create an application to reverse a list by using a linked list based Stack data structure. When you run the program, it asks you to type in an input. When you press Enter, it displays the input in reverse order. You decide the input data type this time.

I made my Node class or Link class, my LinkedList class, LinkedListStack Class, and now i am stuck in the main method.I posted all of my code below in hopes of someone helping me find the error I am making. I looked at other posts but most of them deal with either just reversing a linked list alone, a string, or a linkedlist arraylist.

This is the error I keep getting:

```
Please enter a word: Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at LinkedStackDemo.main(LinkedStackDemo.java:32)


public class Node 
{
  public String data;
  public Node next;

 public Node(String d)
 {
  data = d;
 }
 public void displayNode()
 {
  System.out.println(data + " ");
}
}
```

Linked List Class

```
public class LinkedList
{
   public Node first;

   public LinkedList()
   {
      first = null;
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return (first == null);
   }
   public void insertFirst(String d)
   {
      Node n = new Node(d);
      n.next = first;
      first = n;
   }
   public String deleteFirst() 
   {
      //if(first == null)
       //{return first;}

      Node temp = first;
      first  = first.next;
      //temp.next = null;
      //return temp;
      return temp.data;
   }
   public void displayNode()
   {
      Node current = first;
      while(current != null)
      {
         current.displayNode();
         current = current.next;
      }
      System.out.println(" ");
   }
}
```

Linked Stack Class

```
public class LinkedListStack
{
   private LinkedList node;

   public LinkedListStack()
   {
   node = new LinkedList();
   }
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return node.first == null;
   }
   public void push(String data)
   {
   node.insertFirst(data);
   }
   public String pop()
   {
     return node.deleteFirst();
   }
   public void displayStack()
   {
      System.out.println("Reversed order: ");
      node.displayNode();
   }


}
```

My main method (this is where i am getting very stuck)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
public class LinkedStackDemo
{
   public static void main(String []args)
   {
      LinkedListStack s = new LinkedListStack();
      LinkedList s1 = new LinkedList();
      String input;
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Please enter a word: ");
      input = scan.nextLine();

      s.push(input);



      //String reverse = new    StringBuffer(s.push(input)).reverse().toString();
      //System.out.println(reverse);



     for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++)
{
    while(i<=input.length())
        {


         String c = input.substring(i,i-1);
        s.push(c);

        }
       //System.out.println("The stack is:\n"+ s);
       s.displayStack();
}



}


   }
```

---

I fixed the most recent problem but now it prints the code vertically instead of horizontally, this was my most recent problem.

This how it prints it out, the desired output would be to print the reverse like this, " olleH "Please enter a word: Hello Reversed order: H Hello Reversed order: e H Hello Reversed order: l e H Hello Reversed order: l l e H Hello Reversed order: o l l e H Hello

Taking out the System.out.println(" "); from displayNode; did not fix the problem for it printing out vertically.

Comment: remove `System.out.println(" ");` from `displayNode()`

Comment: I tried doing that before posting again, it doesnt change how it prints vertically

Comment: See [`String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) : _"`IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this `String` object, or **`beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`**."_ Guess what happens if you use `input.substring(i,i-1)`...

Answer (score 1):

The vast majority of the code here is totally irrelevant to the problem you describe. The only relevant bit is this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input.length(); i++)
{
  while(i<=input.length())
  {
    String c = input.substring(i,i-1);
    s.push(c);
  }
  //System.out.println("The stack is:\n"+ s);
  s.displayStack();
}
```

The actual problem that you're seeing is the exception caused by passing in `i` and `i-1` to `String.substring`.  As it says in the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) (emphasis mine):

> [Throws] `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or **beginIndex is larger than endIndex**.

So, you need to call something else, like `input.substring(i-1, i)`.

But there's another problem here: your `while` loop will never terminate, because `i` and `input` never change, so `i<=input.length()` never changes. As such, you'd just keep on pushing `c` into the stack until you run out of memory.

This `while` loop is simply unnecessary; remove it.

Comment: Thanks, and so I should delete the while loop, keep the String c but fix the substring, and keep s.push(c);  Just to confirm.

Comment: @McDodger try it.

Comment: This how it prints it out, the desired output would be to print the reverse like this, " olleH "Please enter a word: Hello
Reversed order: 
H 
Hello 
 
Reversed order: 
e 
H 
Hello 
 
Reversed order: 
l 
e 
H 
Hello 
 
Reversed order: 
l 
l 
e 
H 
Hello 
 
Reversed order: 
o 
l 
l 
e 
H 
Hello

Comment: I fixed this problem but now it prints out the output vertically instead of horizontally

Comment: That's because you use `println` (print with a newline) in the `Node` class. Use `print` instead.